# Updating an XSLX file which is already in use

Tags: csom, versioning

I am using File.OpenBinaryDirect in Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM to download an .xlsx file from a document library, then change the file and uploaded it again (using File.SaveBinaryDirect).

This works, unless the file is opened by anyone (including myself) in the browser or the Excel desktop application. If that is the case, I receive an error 409 (conflict) when using File.SaveBinaryDirect.

Ideally, I would merge all changes into to file on the Sharepoint server (with my changes winning should a conflict arise). So I don't want full co-authoring (which - I guess - is more complicated or impossible to use with CSOM), but the ability to merge with, or - if that is not possible - to overwrite an already checked out file.

I am including my C# test code but I guess it is of little relevance for the question.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security;
using System.Windows;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

private void Test()
{
    IWorkbook workbook;

    var filename =
        new Uri(@"https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite/Shared%20Documents/SubDir/test.xlsx");
    string server = filename.AbsoluteUri.Replace(filename.AbsolutePath, "");
    string serverRelative = filename.AbsolutePath;

    var context =
        new SP.ClientContext(server);

    var password = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in "mypassword".ToCharArray())
    {
        password.AppendChar(c);
    }
    context.Credentials = new SP.SharePointOnlineCredentials("user123@comany.com", password);

    var fileInfo = SP.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, serverRelative);

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        workbook = WorkbookFactory.Create(memoryStream, ImportOption.All);
    }

    var sheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);

    IRow row;
    row = sheet.GetRow(0);
    if (row == null)
    {
        row = sheet.CreateRow(0);
    }

    var cell0 = row.CreateCell(0);
    cell0.SetCellValue("Test");

    XSSFFormulaEvaluator.EvaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);

    string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

    using (var fs = new FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        workbook.Write(fs);
    }
    workbook.Close();

    using (var fs = new FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        SP.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, serverRelative, fs, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot replace an in-use (or locked) file and there is no mechanism to merge changes (which would require co-authoring which has no developer-facing APIs).

Comment: .....so sad....